# How to Sync an Enterprise Application with a Mobile Application?

Tags: android

I have a problem statement wherein a mobile(Android) app has to be written for Profile Management of the Employees of a company and each Employee would have a Device of his/her own wherein they can store all their personal, Professional, Contact details and training plans.
Now this information would be stored locally on the device's DB but how can this be Synced to the Enterprise Applciation/DB where all the details updated from the mobile device should automatically reflect and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create web services and access database via web sevices.

Answer (score 1):

Once approach would be to use the mobile server from Oracle: http://bit.ly/fmiAre

Please note that mobile server uses Oracle DB, so your enterprise app would need to store its data in Oracle DB for this to work. But if that's not a problem, it could meet your needs quite well. It supports Android and a number of other mobile platforms.

Basically your mobile app would store its data in the local SQLite database just like all the other mobile apps. The sync client would periodically sync with the backend Oracle DB. You can configure this to happen automatically, or control it from your app via the API, it's up to you.

Also if you choose to do so, you can deploy apps directly from the mobile server console to the remote devices, and manage the apps and devices as well.

You can download it here and try it out: http://bit.ly/fMDWMP

Hope that helps. Good luck with solving your problem,

-- Eric, Oracle PM